# For in, go to next when I want in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am making about 20 cell items using for in.

But in for in there is DispatchQueue.main.async and for in goes to the next before it ends.

So I want to finished for in after the DispatchQueue.main.async is finished.

This is the code:

```
for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
{
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
    var photoHeight = CGFloat(50.0)

    _ = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    { (value) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                photoHeight = value

                let height = self.cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
                let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
                let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: self.cellPadding, dy: self.cellPadding)

                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = insetFrame
                self.cache.append(attributes)

                self.contentHeight = max(self.contentHeight, frame.maxY)
                yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height

                column = column < (self.numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
            }
    }

    // DispatchQueue.main.async is not finish, but it runs here.
}
```

Comment: You have two options. Either remove the DispatchQueue.main.async.. so everything will run in serial manner.. Or, you extend the encapsulation of the the DispatchQueue.main.asyn to include everything. That means, you do DispatchQueue.Main.Asyn{ For item in 0...< collectionView.numberOfItems...... the code you want to run finish}.. Depends on your need because I don't know the real reason why DispatchQueue.Main.Async is there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not even need to use `DispathQueue.main.async` here. you are not doing any UI work, so you don't have to be on the main thread.

Asynchronous calls don't run in a sequential order like you would expect. Think of a network call..

```
print('starting network call')

NetworkClient.get(url) { response, error in 
    print('returned from network')
}

print('function complete')
```

If you called this the likely output would be:

> starting network call
>
> function complete
>
> returned from network

This is because the async function is dispatched and takes time to complete, but execution can continue whilst that is going on. Once the network call is done the callback/completion handler will be called and that code will run then.

[Here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476778/returning-data-after-async-task) of async function calls in Swift